# Is Mac faster than Windows PC to edit photos/video?

Tags: windows, mac

Some mac advocates say they are faster than pc's for editing video or photos, even with the same Processor/memory/graphic card.

Though i can measure things like video conversion time, or photo batch processing, those are not really perfect measures for the feel of fluidity on usual work.

It also depends on the software, Premiere, Photoshop and Lightroom are available for both platforms.

So, anyone have ever proposed a way of testing this, and conducted such tests? (or can?)

Or can find results of those batch processing tests?

What about the displays. Some say mac monitors are better, is this because they are glossy?

Comment: Mac "advocates" will always say that a Mac will beat a PC... at anything. Haven't you seen the commercials?

Answer (score 4):

I have used both Mac and PC to edit Photo/video both with top of the line specs.

Is mac better than PC? In my opinion no. The speeds are comparable. For me it comes down to how many other programs do you put on the computer and have running while working on photo/video.

If you create and use a dedicated computer then I think the difference will not be noticeable.

How to test this? I am unsure. As for monitors I think that comes down to personal opinion. Look at two (side by side if possible) and see what your eye sees. If you prefer with one over the other go with it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: you never timed the same batch processing over 2 machines? what about monitor, what you prefer?

Comment: I do not do batch processing with what I was doing so it is hard for me to say there. As for monitors I was using what was avaliable as I did not own the systems just used what was there. For my personal use I use a LG monitor and it works great. I have no desire to pay some of the prices that Mac charges for monitors. I go to places like CNet, read reviews, then look in store if avaliable. Then make my purchase decision.

Comment: One other note: What are you most comfortable with?

Comment: i really never used a mac heavily, as my main computer.. so i can't say

Answer (score 3):

### There is no difference!

It's ultimately about what **YOU** feel comfortable working with and what you are used to.

---

> So, anyone have ever proposed a way of testing this, and conducted such tests? (or can?)

You can run a usability experiment where you give a set of test persons the same task, for example: "Import 20 RAW photos from a camera, edit them, burn them to a CD and make a slideshow" (of course, way more detailed, but you get the hang of it).

This experiment would then measure how long it takes for the task to be completed, and how satisfied the test persons were.

The problem is that all those test persons should not be biased towards either platform and should have no experience with either one. Where do you find such people? It's hard to imagine you would find someone who hasn't used either. And if you want to find people with experience in both, how do you define "equally experienced"?

Then again, the only difference (so to speak, "variable") in your experiment should be the platform (i.e. Mac or Windows-based PC), so that's another problem. You would have to run the test with *exactly the same software* and hardware to be able to say: "Mac is better than PC, given the same software and the same task, and the same people". If the software changed, you would be bound to say: "Mac is better than PC, but we used different software, so, it's not a good comparison". Same for hardware.

You could obviously also test professionals in the same manner. And as you can see, even in this very very simplified example, you run into problems that run out of hand when you want to do a real "Is Mac better than PC" test.

> Some say mac monitors are better, is this because they are glossy?

Then those people obviously have never seen a good monitor. Glossy monitors tend to accentuate  colors and contrast, therefore giving us the impression of a more vivid picture. On the other hand, forget those for editing videos or photos. Their color representation is nowhere near perfect and a professional in video/photo editing would **never ever** use a glossy monitor.

---

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest go for Windows. You can use image-editing apps from number of different vendors with one better over the other in various ways. For example, MS latest release for [Camara Codec Pack](http://g.live.com/dmxpgen-us/140) now supports raw format directly from (number of) cameras from various vendors which can further be accessed in Windows Live Photo Gallery. More details on this [here](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2011/07/26/photo-gallery-now-supports-raw-format.aspx).

Comment: I don't know.. don't want to start a discussion, but my Mac has been showing RAW previews for a loooong time now. *"> You can use image-editing apps from number of different vendors"* -- and you can't do that on a Mac?

Comment: 'don't want to start a discussion' yeah me too.. RAW images were supported on Windows for looong time too.. by this -> http://g.live.com/dmxpgen-us/140 I mean enhancement in the newly introduce APPS like live-essentials'! (btw it’s a must try suite..) Besides check-out the number of supported cams in the list, you would admire it ;-)